# How to output a column per group that an item is a member of?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Given this SQL Input Table

```
GroupId   Item
1         Fish
1         FishBowl
2         Fish
3         Fish
```

How Can i derive this Output?

```
Item     IsInGroup1   IsInGroup2   IsInGroup3
Fish     Y            Y            Y
FishBowl Y            N            N
```

Please note that the Number of Groups can be variable

Comment: Please post the table schemas and test data. Not that those who respond will need that in order to tell you to use the PIVOT operator, but it's good practice.

Comment: How will pivot work for variable groups ?

Comment: It will create one column per value of the GroupId column. In your example, there will be three columns, named [1], [2] and [3]. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't do a variable number of groups with standard SQL.  You have to know the groups beforehand.  This is because any SQL query must know the number of columns, and their names.

```
SELECT Item, 
  MAX(CASE GroupId WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS IsInGroup1, 
  MAX(CASE GroupId WHEN 2 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS IsInGroup2, 
  MAX(CASE GroupId WHEN 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS IsInGroup3
FROM ThisInputTable
GROUP BY Item;
```

Microsoft SQL Server does have some facility for PIVOT tables, however this is not standard SQL.  I'm not a Microsoft user so I'll give you a link to "[Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)," and leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005) [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991951/sql-select-two-dimensional-select-with-variable-column-count) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns-sql-problem) on SO.

Basically, you can use dynamic SQL to build a query of the form Bill Karwin gives by determining the number of groups and a name for each group.  Such a query you generate can be ANSI SQL.  You can also generate proprietary syntax for SQL Server 2008 (2005 and above)'s PIVOT operator which Bill mentioned.

My example at the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005) should be pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose it depends on which database you are using. This works for me:

SELECT
 Item,
 IF(GroupId=1,'Y','N') As `IsInGroup1`,
 IF(GroupId=2,'Y','N') As `IsInGroup2`,
 IF(GroupId=3,'Y','N') As `IsInGroup3`
FROM
 `New Table`
GROUP BY
 Item ;

Comment: Looks like MySQL syntax.  Microsoft SQL Server will complain about that use of GROUP BY.  Also MS SQL Server doesn't have an IF() function that works as it does in MySQL.

Comment: For ANSI compatibility, you would need to use MAX(GroupId), since you cannot return a result that is not in the GROUP BY or a result of an aggregate function on the set.