# need Sql query (may be pivot)

Tags: sql, pivot

i have table like below ,

```
Product Name   Price   Date
Apple          1.5     5/5/2009
Apple          3       5/6/2009
Apple          3.5     5/7/2009
Apple          2.5     5/8/2009
Apple          5.5     5/9/2009
Orange         10.5    5/5/2009
Orange         12.5    5/6/2009
Orange         7.5     5/7/2009
Orange         4.5     5/8/2009
Orange         5.5     5/9/2009
```

I need output like below:

```
Product Name  5/5/2009   5/6/2009    5/7/2009    5/8/2009  5/9/2009
Apple          1.5        3          3.5         2.5       5.5
Orange        10.5       12.5        7.5         4.5       5.5
```

also date increases column also need to increase,
Pls help me

Vickees

Comment: Plz edit using the "code" buttom.

Comment: Also, when you post a question about databases, always post the schema of the relevant tables. You may even want to include SQL to create the test data. That way, those who want to help you can create the exact same scenario you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

the answer depends on which database you are using, but you may benefit from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999067/how-to-output-a-column-per-group-that-an-item-is-a-member-of)

please note that this is a very popular question on SO.  you would be best served by searching for related topics.  i think there you will have the benefit of many different perspectives, not just those of the users logged in at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
select [Product name], //Give me all of the Fruit
sum(case when date = '5/05/09' then Price end as [5/5/09], // Sum Case Allow for multiple record on the same day
sum(case when date = '5/06/09' then Price end as [5/6/09],
sum(case when date = '5/07/09' then Price end as [5/7/09],
sum(case when date = '5/08/09' then Price end as [5/8/09],
sum(case when date = '5/09/09' then Price end as [5/9/09]
from tblfruits
group by [Product Name]
```